# Ubuntu Software Center .deb installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, debian, deb

I created a .deb package and it can be installed via *'dpkg -i'* perfectly or using *GDebi* but I don't want to ask users to install additional tools.

The package is intended to be for *low level users* so I want them to be able to install it using **Ubuntu Software Center.**

I have a *postinst script* which asks questions interactively after installation via **zenity** tool.

When I try to install it using *Ubuntu Software Center* the dialog window **never** appears during installation and software center waits for input.

How can I allow postinst script to show the **GUI window** during installation in *Ubuntu Software Center*?

Comment: What is your question, here? Please clarify.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae edited